# Permalinks only for posts

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I would like to use wordpress permalinks but **only** for posts. Is there any way to do that?

I don't care about seo, my website is about niche subject so it already has first position in google. Also enabling permalinks makes some conflicts with plugins I have installed.

I would be completly fine without permalinks but I don't like appearance of post's links - ?p=some_numbers - instead of that I would like something prettier, like post name and date.

How can I achieve that without enabling permalinks? Maybe somehow in .htacces file? But then how do I get post name?

Or maybe I should use permalinks but edit rewrite rules (honestly I have no idea how to do that)?

Comment: Which plugins do you run that don't support permalinks? If it's true that they don't support such a basic feature, I would be very wary of relying on them.

Comment: It's not like they don't support it, it's rather than two diffrent plugins are going in their ways when permalinks are enabled.

Also I have nothing against links like ?key=value, I think in my case it'more clear than /key/value or something like that. Only exception where I prefer pretty links are posts (and pages, but I have only few on me site so it's not a big problem).